# Is this an argument against an experience machine?

Tags: meaning-of-life

Is this an argument against an experience machine, that the things we value inside of it only matter to us?

I'm trying to be practical about having strange concerns, and wondered whether their uniqueness to me means not only that they likely *can't happen* but also that they **are meaningless**.

So, even if I spent some time climbing Everest in an experience machine, does the very fact that no-one else thinks it's an achievement make it a meaningless experience? If I climbed it with someone else (also hooked up into the machine), would that make it meaningful? What if I didn't know they were? etc.

Comment: If you can make a living out of such VR machine or metaverse project then certainly it's meaningful to you and your colleagues as I'm sure you cannot achieve so as a one-person shop. Per Zeno the Stoic founder self-preservation acts are relatively valuable (though Cynics may reject) but has nothing to do with anyone's happiness which depends only on moral actions. Since any true moral action must be *necessarily* consistent with some *idea of justice* which inevitably involves other people, that's why in your deep heart you rightly feel true happiness must involve others' happiness...

Answer (score 1):

Something is meaningful only because it means something to someone. Provided that even a single person thinks it is meaningful, then it is. It may not be to other people, but to this one person, it means something.

By experience machine I assume you mean a machine designed to replicate the feeling of actual experiences, like some sort of souped up VR thing.

Now, if it means something to you to climb a mountain in VR, I cannot argue; it is fully your decision to make something meaningful. Whether or not other people find it meaningful does not discount the meaning you find. However, I would advise to take into account where others find or do not find meaning. Oftentimes they have good points.

So, your experience machine can be meaningful so long as you make it so. Though, as a matter of personal opinion, I would much rather climb a real mountain than a simulated one.

Comment: just a statement of belief. I appreciate mine was also, but I did add a bit of context (madness etc.)

Answer (score 1):

> So, even if I spent some time climbing Everest in an experience machine, does the very fact that no-one else thinks it's an achievement make it a meaningless experience?

We've got those "experience machines" already.

[image: Getting Over It with Bennett Foddy]

"Climbing" to the top of this "mountain" is *difficult*. Not everyone can do it – though many people are capable of *becoming* able to do it. The "mountain" is not a real object. And yet, people consider "scaling" it an achievement.

But suppose other people *didn't* consider this an achievement. There are people who don't; suppose the whole world (except you) is populated by such people. Does that affect the meaningfulness of the achievement? What about the meaningfulness of the *experience*, which nobody else was party to *anyway*?

If an experience can be *inherently* meaningful, I don't see how things outside the experience should affect its meaningfulness. If something else gives experiences meaning, you already have an answer to this question.

(Note: this interpretation of an experience machine is atypical.)

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. meaningful iff intrinsically so. but isn't it more reasonable to suppose that it's being with others (don't mean that technically) that makes life, and so experiences, meaningful?

Comment: @sock_muppet Not _inherently_. If you feel that's what gives life meaning, then it probably gives _your_ life meaning. Unless you're arriving to that conclusion from pure reason, though, "reasonableness" has nothing to do with it.

Comment: well yes, other people aren't inherent to my life. i can imagine some people who have meaningful lives utterly alone, but IME it would just be hedonism.

Comment: Their hedonism is meaningless to _you_, but does that mean it is absent of any meaning to anybody? All things are meaningless hedonism, from a certain perspective.

Comment: no, feelings of pleasure or power or whatever *can* be meaningful. but they are more coarsely futile, in my opinion. unlike achievements, which may always involve others, hedonism truly is transient and bound to our mortal lifespan, imho. first and last vs me. objective events vs subjective states

Comment: @sock_muppet Oh, your question is about whether something _has been achieved_?

Comment: maybe indirectly! if no-one agrees it is an achievement, a goal achieved, then is the only meaning we can take from it hedonistic, and does that limit the scope of meaning to something more profoundly absurd.

Comment: @sock_muppet Why is it more meaningful if other people agree it's an achievement?

Comment: ime if you are completely alone (a solipsist e.g.) then you can achieve nothing meaningful, because you are left with nothing but your sensations. at least some people seem to think that the existence of other people makes for a wider range of meaning and duty. else what could legislate anything, except our own feelings (or God etc.)? when with others, you can base your value judgments on ideals that are alien to you. IME empathy works that way.

Answer (score 0):

"*if I spent some time climbing Everest in an experience machine, does the very fact that no-one else thinks it's an achievement make it a meaningless experience? If I climbed it with someone else (also hooked up into the machine), would that make it meaningful? What if I didn't know they were? etc.*"

[Ludwig Binswanger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Binswanger) (1881-1966) had an opinion on shared versus private experience, especially as a psychiatrist.  He emphasised the value of being in the *Mitwelt*—the shared world—as opposed to the *Eigenwelt*—one's own world.

He wrote about this in 1930s essay *Traum und Existenz* (Dream and existence):

> For Heraclitus, genuine awakeness is, negatively put, the awakening
> from private opinion (*doxa*) and subjective belief. Put positively, it
> is life (and not just the life of thought!) that accords with the laws
> of the universal, whether this universal be called *logos*, *cosmos*,
> *sophia*, or whether it is considered as a combination of all of them in
> the sense of a rational insight into their unitary, lawful
> interrelation and in the sense of action according to this insight.
> Hegel presents this Heraclitean doctrine by saying that here Reason,
> Logos, becomes the judge of Truth—not, however, of truth that is
> second best, but, rather, of divine, universal truth: "this measure,
> this rhythm which penetrates through to the essence of the All" (an
> echo of the ancient συμπάθεια - *sumpathíā*).
>
> To the extent that we participate knowingly in the divine
> understanding we participate in the Truth; but to the extent that we
> are particular and special, (ίδιάσωμεν), we are deceived. According to
> Hegel, these are very great and important words:
>
> > Nothing truer or more unprejudiced can be said about Truth. Only
> > consciousness of the universal is consciousness of truth; but
> > consciousness of particularity and particular action, originality
> > which results in idiosyncracy of content or form, is untrue and evil.
> > Error, therefore, consists solely in the particularization of
> > thought—evil and error consist in the divorce from the universal. Most
> > men think that their conceptions should be something special and
> > original; precisely this is illusion.
>
> According to Hegel, "the knowledge of something of which only I am
> aware" is just dreaming, and the same is true of imagination (in the
> sense of phantasy) and emotion ...

However, some sharp criticism could be made of this neat distinction and the higher value given to the *Mitwelt*.  One, for example, from Nietzsche, quoted by Derrida in *The Question of Being & History*, [p.211](https://books.google.gg/books?id=IpqFDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA221).  One can imagine Nietzsche would certainly find some fault with the *Mitwelt* of today's crazy politics.

> > I believe there has been no dangerous vacillation or crisis of German
> > culture this century that has not been rendered more dangerous by the
> > enormous and still continuing influence of this philosophy, the
> > Hegelian. ...
> >
> > History understood in this Hegelian fashion has been
> > mockingly called God’s sojourn on earth, though the god referred to
> > has been created only by history. ...
>
> You see what is signified by the accusation of vulgarity that Hegel
> and Nietzsche are flinging, or would fling, at each other. Now you
> know that if, as we saw, what governs the whole of Hegelianism in
> Heidegger’s view is a *vulgar* (his word) concept of time as
> intra-temporality, worldly temporality thought in the mode of the movement
> of *Vorhandenheit*, Heidegger says elsewhere, in passages I read at
> the beginning of the year, that Nietzsche is merely a reversal of
> Hegel: that is, he still belongs to the sphere of metaphysics in which
> this reversal takes place. He too, then, would be a victim of Hegelian
> *vulgarity*.

Heidegger joins the interior world with the exterior, but both retain different characteristics.  Climbing Everest in an experience machine by oneself is not a meaningless experience, but you won't get a medal unless you do it in the shared world.